# How to stop thread(s) properly while using CyclicBarriers

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, cyclicbarrier

I have to make operations on a cache using many threads and thus have created 3 classes that extends from Thread (I realize now they can be Runnables also, or should be). Careful to note, these I'm running more than 1 instance of one of these threads but not at the same time. As in:

```
public class Operation1 extends Thread
public class Operation2 extends Thread
public class Operation3 extends Thread

Thread[] operation1Threads = new Thread[5];
```

So after I finish with this one, I create new threads for the second operation (at random). 
The following is the way my run method is created.
I make use of cyclic barriers to wait for the threads to work at the same time.

```
public volatile boolean running = true;
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        cyclicbarrier1.await();
        //some operation here
        cyclicbarrier2.await();
    }
}
```

The main thread is focusing on how long to run these for and at the end of that time, I try to stop the threads before working on the second operation. But it seems that my threads don't actually stop.

EDIT: I should note that I've tried interrupting the thread directly. And tried to reset the barrier both of which seemed to be bad practices from answers found on other threads.

```
for (int i=0; i < numthreads; i++) {
    ops[i].interrupt();    
}
```

I use an ExecutorService to manage these operations sequentially.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
es.submit(new Operation1Runnable()); 
es.submit(new Operation2Runnable());
```

But the executorservice doesn't go to the next one.

Comment: In java you can't stop a thread. If you interrupt a thread, it's up to the code in the thread to catch the exception and exit from the run method of the thread. Why do you want to stop threads?

Comment: You should describe the problem you're actually trying to solve. Stopping threads may not actually be what you should be attempting.